# How to create an DOM element in an object oriented way?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know that you can create any element, such as an "a" tag, using

```
document.createElement('a')
```

How do you design this in a more object oriented way? Is this the right way to do it?

```
function Button(){
  this.style.tagName = 'a';
  this.setAttribute('href', some_link);
  this.style.padding = '10px';
}

var pinkButton = new Button();
pinkButton.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';

document.getElementById('blah').appendChild(pinkButton)
```

and have it appear on the page under element ID `'blah'`

Comment: What makes you believe that factory functions like `createElement` are not object-oriented?

Comment: What is `this.attribute` referencing? `this.backgroundColor` should be `this.style.backgroundColor`. Though `document.createElement("a")` is simplest approach

Comment: Your `pinkButton` initialisation is a syntax mistake in JavaScript (not actually a syntax error, as it's valid but does something completely different from what you intended).

Comment: yeah I meant `style`

Comment: @Bergi you are right. I corrected it. It is object oriented but I just want to create my own buttons since I have so many types and want them to be similar.

Comment: I also want to set default `onclick` functions for each type of buttons, and they are not exactly the same

Comment: @guest: No, you can't subclass `HTMLButtonElement` (or `HTMLAnchorElement`) in JS. Subclasses aren't a solution to "many types of similar buttons" anyway. Rather have a look at the builder pattern or mixins.

Comment: It's not that simple. I'm building something that is used by thousands of sites and I'm not allowed to change their CSS. I can only use my own JS to set classes...I guess you could say I could create a style element and append it, but I don't want the style to create conflicts with existing styles.

Comment: @Bergi yes you can't subclass but you can create your own class without subclassing.

Comment: Imagine what Google maps is doing on a small scale. Google appends styles to their map elements, so I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you basically want to subtype button then you can do something like this

```
var customButtonFactory = function(bgColor){
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.style.background = bgColor;
  //do all the other custom styling you want for the button
  return button;
}
```

it depends how different the onclick functions are you can either pass in some parameter to build the function inside the factory... or you could straight up pass the function in as a paramater.

Comment: oh OK...I see the structure now! this is very helpful! thank you!

Comment: You generally should lowercase functions that are not constructors, though.